# How to use dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane Events

Tags: dojo

ScrollablePane in dojo mobile have some event that we can use as they have mentioned in their API [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/). I try to use the as follows.

```
leftPane.on("onTouchEnd", function(e){
alert("sss");
});
```

(leftPane is a ScrollablePane) This does not work. But this works when I use a event like "click". I search throughout the net for a example but didn't find a one. Can someone help me out here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
aspect.after(leftPane, 'onTouchEnd', function(e) { });
```

dojo/on is tricky when it comes to the event naming - you could start by ditching the "on" prefix. Most likely, simply changing `onTouchEnd` to `touchend` would work

Answer (score 1):

The Dojo event system changed significantly between 1.6 and 1.7.  The new `on` function and the `Evented` mixin is the recommended way of handling events in widgets, but there are some backward-compatibility functions in the `_WidgetBase` class.

In short, you can either use the legacy `dojo.connect` function, the new `aspect` function (which implementes the "connect to normal javascript method" functionality of the old `dojo.connect`), or use the new `on` method in the `_WidgetBase` class that is a bridge between the two.

```
1. dojo.connect(leftPane, 'onTouchEnd', function(e) { });
2. aspect.after(leftPane, 'onTouchEnd', function(e) { }, true);  // <-- the 'true' is important!
3. leftPane.on('touchend', function(e) { });
```

YMMV on (3) depending on whether the widget was updated to provide this bridging.